# Cast string 'May 11 2022 9:16AM' to a timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I have this query:

```
select to_timestamp('May 11 2022  9:16AM', 'Month DD YYYY HH:MI')
```

Returns: `2022-05-11 09:16:00.000 -0300`

The expression `'Month DD YYYY HH:MI'` is the result of some trial and error.

I can't tell if what I have is 'right'? Expected something more like: `2022-05-11 09:16:00`

What is `...00.000 -0300` this part?

How can I get a timestamp from `May 11 2022  9:16AM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the docs [Data Type Formatting Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) `to_timestamp`:

> to_timestamp ( text, text ) → timestamp with time zone

> Converts string to time stamp according to the given format. (See also to_timestamp(double precision) in Table 9.32.)

> to_timestamp('05 Dec 2000', 'DD Mon YYYY') → 2000-12-05 00:00:00-05

So what you are seeing is a `timestamptz` value, e.g a timestamp with time zone information. If you want to eliminate the time zone then:

```
select to_timestamp('May 11 2022  9:16AM', 'Month DD YYYY HH:MI')::timestamp;
    to_timestamp     
---------------------
 2022-05-11 09:16:00
```